# Log Audit file when update mySQL and Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, perl-module

The want a Perl script that will write to  a data file every time update the Database MySQL. I dont mind about growth of the file since Every Items audited will be stored seperatly

Thank you will Appreciate you Help

Comment: Please don't use signature links in your posts.  Your gravatar already "signs" your question.  You can put a link to your site in your profile.

Answer (score 1):

The module [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.32/) provides many different ways to log events to many types of output including files. It also would allow you to set debug levels to turn this off if you needed to.